# Regex to match next 1 to 3 words and anyting after

Tags: regex

My regex is:

```
Paragraph 1[34]{1}(\w+\s?){1,5}[\s\S]*?\WReturn Amount\W\shas the meaning specified in\s(Paragraph \S+)\sof this Annex
```

My string is:

```
Paragraph 13 Elections Variables something
next line something else "Return Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 3(b) of this Annex.
```

I am expecting a group called Paragraph 13 Elections Variables something
and a group Paragraph 3(b)
The first group could have from 1 to 5 words.

The above regex doesn't seem to work - any ideas on what to fix?

Comment: The first thing that stands out to me is that you are missing a space after `Paragraph 1[34]`

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to group the words between "Election Variables" and "Return Amount"? The description to your problem is not very clear...
I'd try something like this:
`Paragraph (\d+|\d+\(\w+\)) ((\w+\s+){1,5})`
`Paragraph (\d+|\(\d+\))` - matches `Paragraph` a space, zero or more digits, or zero or more digits inside parenthesis

`((\w+\s+){1,5})` - matches zero or more word characters and zero or more spaces after the word match. The `{1,5}` is supposed to repeat the match 1 or up to 3 times.

edit: I updated my answer based on your comment. If you need to be specific on the numbers themselves, replace `\d+` with the number you need.

edit 2: Ok I came up with this- `Paragraph \d+(.*\n).*Paragraph \d\(\w+\)(.*)` First group matches anything after `Paragraph 13` and second groupd matches anything after `Paragraph (b)`

Check out here: https://regex101.com/r/dD7NM9/1

Comment: I'm trying to match the next 1 to 5 words after Paragraph 13 and then a separate group later that matches Paragraph 3(b)

Comment: Does that work? edit: wait I think I understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `Paragraph ([\w()]+ ?\n?){1,6}`.

`[\w()]+` - match any word character or `(` or `)` one or more times,

`?\n?` - match space and new line at most once (separately),

`{1,6}` - match group at least one, at most 6 times, you wanted at most 5 words, but I am counting also `13` and `3(b)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Py8IHO/1)

Answer (score 0):

You miss a space after the paragrph number:

```
Paragraph 1[34] (\w+\s?){1,5}[\s\S]*?\WReturn Amount\W\shas the meaning specified in\s(Paragraph \S+)\sof this Annex
        here __^
```

I removed `{1}` that is superfluous.

Comment: This doesn;t match any of the words after Paragraph 13 for some reason

Comment: @Gretel: What language/tool are you using? Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51675389/edit) your question and add expected result.